# Lint error "ImpliedQuantity" when wrapping plurals item in CDATA

Tags: android, android-lint

Seems like the `ImpliedQuantity` lint check triggers a false positive when plural items are wrapped in `CDATA`.

For example, having these resources in the French `strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <plurals name="test">
        <item quantity="one">%d baguette</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d baguettes</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

...passes the lint check, but this does not:

```
<resources>
    <plurals name="test">
        <item quantity="one"><![CDATA[%d <b>baguette</b>]]></item>
        <item quantity="other">%d baguettes</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

Comment: Same. Could only get around this by using `tools:ignore="ImpliedQuantity, MissingQuantity"`. implied for the lint rule bug and missing for android not complaning about `many` quantitiy entry.